# httpd restart error : Apache

Tags: apache

When I tried to restart httpd, I am getting below error.

```
[admin@stg-001 ~]$ /apps/apache/bin/httpd -k restart
```

`httpd: Syntax error on line 114 of /apps/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /apps/apache/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file:`
No such file or directory
Server version: `Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)`

Please help me to resolve the error.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following command, which shows required modules which are missing.

```
ldd (apache_home_dir)/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Will produce something like:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc61f7a000)        
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f71c9666000)
```

Below Fix Worked for me:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_to_openssl/lib/
```

or try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_to_openssl/
```

Ref: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?s=2bcf368edb2a95bce9e538e8db2aed76&p=5605966#post5605966

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the error message?

Check that the line 114 of /apps/apache/conf/httpd.conf is syntatically correct

Check that the file /apps/apache/modules/mod_ssl.so exists

Comment: Hi Ed Heal, 
line 114 says LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
I dont see any syntax error in that line. PLease correc me if I am wrong.
I checked the path /apps/apache/modules/mod_ssl.so exists

Any more suggestions will be a great help

Comment: @Techno_Feast - File permissions. Valid file (i.e. not corrupt)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that libssl is indeed installed on your server with the proper version.
You can check in /var/lib (depends on you OS)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on centos, the fix for us was this command

```
yum install compat-openssl10
```